# Check range of string values that contains a number

Tags: c#

I have a list of values for example: G1, G2, G2.5, G3, G4, etc..) How can I check a range of these values in c# say if I wanted to see if value was between G1 and G2.5 ?

In Vb.net I can do:

```
        Select Case selectedValue
           Case "G1" To "G2.5" //This would be true for G1, G2, and G2.5
```

How can I do this in c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Remove the `G` from `selectedValue`
2. Parse the remaining into a `decimal`
3. Implement your logic against the decimal value

-

```
var number = decimal.Parse(selectedValue.Replace("G", ""));
if (number >= 1.0m && number <= 2.5m)
{
    // logic here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think any of these answers would work, but your's is the least amount of code. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

To do string comparison, you could just do this

```
if (string.Compare(selectedValue, "G1") >= 0 && string.Compare(selectedValue, "G2.5") <= 0)
{
    ...
}
```

But to do numeric comparison, you'd have to parse it as a number (`double` or `decimal`)

```
var selectedValueWithoutG = selectedValue.Substring(1);
var number = decimal.Parse(selectedValueWithoutG);
if (number >= 1D && number <= 2.5D)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to parse your value:

```
var number = decimal.Parse(selectedValue.Substring(1))
```

Then you can apply an extension method like this:

```
bool Between(this int value, int left, int right)
{ 
    return value >= left && value <= right; 
}

if(number.Between(1, 2.5)) {.....}
```